# Why would ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream return null in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, classpath

This same statement works just fine in my actual application (web service):

```
InputStream is = ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(
  "file:/C:/Users/withheld/workspace/myproj/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/myproj.properties");
```

But inside a JUnit test module, it just keeps returning null.

Why?

At first, I thought this was a classpath issue, so I added a path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066783/1864054).

But that didn't help.

So, I forced a brute absolute path, using the method described in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153413/1864054).

But it still returning null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt that it works even in your actual application.

Comment: @BheshGurung Why? I can't argue with results actually read and used from that `myproj.properties`... Please explain.

Comment: If you are really sure that it works then it must a custom classloader in case of the actual application. It's obvious that it's not the same classloader that you have when you run your tests. IMHO, I think it will be better for you to read up a bit on how the resources in classpath are read generally using class and classloader generally and use that instead because that would be portable.

Comment: @BheshGurung I agree. JUnit must be using something else but I am not familiar with what JUnit uses. I tried the original `InputStream is = ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/myproj.properties");` as well, but still null result.

Comment: That looks little better. Now you need to make sure that the folder, where that file is located, is added to the classpath while executing your tests. e.g. `WEB-INF/classes` inside the war is automatically added to the classpath by the server when the war is deployed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using maven (based on the paths in your project).  The `classes` directory under `WEB-INF` should be on the classpath when your web application is loaded, so try the following:

```
InputStream is = ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/myproj.properties");
```

Note that this assumes you have `myproj.properties` in either your `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` directory (it will automatically get copied to `WEB-INF/classes` when maven builds the war or runs the tests).

Comment: Yes, your assumption was correct, I am using Maven. And... for the life of me, I swear I tried your `"/myproj.properties"` (without success), but now, for some strange reason, it works! I most certainly understand now **why** it works (after printing the classpath at runtime), but why it didn't work before is beyond me. Thanks +1 and accepting.

Comment: My guess is that you did `getResourceAsStream("myproj.properties")` (notice the missing leading `/` slash) - which doesn't work.  I've made this mistake many times before myself!